# Elastic Search Digital Ocean

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch, digital-ocean

I tried to install elasticsearch in my droplet on Digital Ocean.

When I execute command to start elasticsearch,

```
cd /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin
./elasticsearch
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapException: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config
Likely root cause: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(UnixFileAttributeViews.java:55)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:144)
    at sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(LinuxFileSystemProvider.java:99)
    at java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1737)
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.getAttributes(FileTreeWalker.java:225)
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.visit(FileTreeWalker.java:276)
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.walk(FileTreeWalker.java:322)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2662)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:100)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:83)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:272)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:121)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:112)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.SettingCommand.execute(SettingCommand.java:54)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:96)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:62)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:89)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:82)
Refer to the log for complete error details.
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem occurs when you have installed elasticsearch via a package but are attempting to run via the command line instead of the service.

Try this instead:

```
sudo service elasticsearch start
```

Also, try changing `#START_DAEMON` to`START_DAEMON` (if it's not already uncommented) in `/etc/default/elasticsearch` and then restart the service.

If you absolutely must run it from the command line then try the archive distribution instead.

[[More](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/21118)]

Comment: Try doing `sudo apt-get purge elasticsearch &&
sudo apt-get install elasticsearch &&
sudo systemctl restart elasticsearch` and report again

Comment: Which version of ubuntu is this?

Comment: @LucasLopes Also, try uncommenting `START_DAEMON`, see my edit above

Comment: @PANAYIOTIS Can you please take a look at the following question:https://stackoverflow.com/q/66858780/9409877